# DNS problem with ipv6 on centos6

Tags: dns, git, ipv6, github, openstack

I have a couple of open-stack instances that communicates with `github.com`. When any of these machines reboots , the file `/etc/resolv.conf` gets the ipv6 addresses of my DNS servers. Everything still works , but i can no longer ping `github.com` and no git-hub related operation works, such as cloning a repo , or pushing something to github ... etc.

Then i have to manually enter the ipv4 addresses of my DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` , and it works again. What is the problem,  and any permanent solution? How can i force the DNS `/etc/resolv.conf` to get ipv4 nameserver addresses instead of ipv6 ? , on reboot.

Comment: You can either give them static addresses, or you can direct the dhcp client to ignore the DNS IPv6 servers given by DHCP, or ignore the DNS servers given by DHCP and having them configured by hand. Are you using dhclient or dhcpcd?

Comment: Thanks , but if i configure static and ignore dhcp , then it will be a problem when the ip addresses of dns servers change. The DNS servers are in separate administration. Yes , it is the dhclient.

Comment: You can comment out dhcp6.name-servers from the request line of dhclient.conf, and will still receive IPv4 DNSes with the directive domain-name that is there.

Comment: I mean , how can i force dhclient to put ipv4 addresses in `/etc/resolv.cof`

Comment: so, did it work?

Comment: i think i should write my own dhclient.conf from some sample , because there is no such file , in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d`

Comment: Mine is /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf, but then I am using Debian